# SQL conditional select with for/while loop

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, conditional-statements

This is the table:

```
Order_ID|Priority|Status 
A       |3       |Normal
A       |4       |Urgent
B       |6       |Urgent
B       |7       |Normal 
C       |8       |Normal
C       |9       |Urgent
```

How do I select the Order_ID and Status where a row's priority is higher for that ID? For example, in this case, the output of the query given the above data should be:

```
A - Urgent
B - Normal
C - Urgent
```

Comment: For future reference, I suggest, for these types of questions, you provide copy+paste-able DDL and DML statements to motivate better answers that take less time to create. For example, if there were a unique constraint (order_id, priority), then the solution might be easier to create than if there were a unique constraint (order_id, priority, create_date) (i.e., if there were a create_date indicating when the priority changed), or no unique constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
select order_id || ' - ' || status
from (
    select order_id, priority, status,
           rank() over (partition by order_id order by priority desc) ranking
    from table
)
where ranking = 1;
```

Comment: I'm very fond of windowing functions. They make things like this tons easier. And to OP, Also note that this solution (rank()) will return multiple rows for an order_id if it has 2 of the same highest priority.

Comment: @Shawn Which is why I like to suggest to the OP for these types of questions to provide copy+paste-able DDL and DML statements to motivate better answers that take less time to create.

Answer (score 1):

The record with the highest priority -->> there is no record with a higher priority

---

```
SELECT *
FROM order_status o
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM order_status x
        WHERE x.order_id = o.order_id
        AND x.priority > o.priority
        )
        ;
```

Comment: This requires two passes on the table, which won't be a big deal if a profile of an execution of the business task shows this query at the bottom of the contributors to total response time.

Comment: The resulting plan depens on the query planner/generator and the availability of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this with SQL would be to simply get the `MAX(Priority)` for each Order_ID and join back to that table using a SUBSELECT:

```
SELECT  x.ORDER_ID + ' - ' + x.Status AS [Output],
    x.Priority ,
    x.Status
FROM    ( SELECT    Order_ID AS Order_ID ,
                MAX(Priority) AS [Priority]
      FROM      @your_table
      GROUP BY ORDER_ID
    ) t
    JOIN @your_table x ON x.Order_ID = t.Order_ID
                       AND x.[Priority] = t.[Priority];
```

Where `@your_table` is whatever the name of your table is.

This is the output of the query:

```
Output      Priority    Status
A - Urgent  4           Urgent
B - Normal  7           Normal
C - Urgent  9           Urgent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Order_ID || ' - ' || (
    select top 1 Status
    from priorities as p2
    where p1.Order_ID = p2.Order_ID 
    order by p2.Priority desc)
from priorities as p1
group by Order_ID
order by max(Priority)
```

Returns

```
A - Urgent
B - Normal
C - Urgent
```